# tikz: Different styles across a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to have a line partially dotted. I have accomplished it with an horizontal line, by inserting a node to delete that part of the line and then drawing a new line.
However, for bended lines I think I must calculate intersections but it does not work as I expect.
I wonder if there is a simpler and more straight way to do it.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, arrows, calc, intersections}
\tikzset{hidden node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=.8cm,inner sep=0pt}, }
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[hidden node] (noiseVar) at (5,4) {$\sigma^2_n$};
\node[hidden node] (noise) at (0,4) {$\varepsilon$};
\node[hidden node] (x) at (0,0) {$x$};

\draw[line width=2] (noiseVar) to node (midf) [pos=.3, fill=white, minimum width = .8cm] {} (noise);
\draw[dot diameter = 2pt, dot spacing = .3cm, dots] (midf.east) to (midf.west);

\draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt, name path=varToNoise] (noiseVar) to node (midn) [pos=.3, fill=white, minimum width = .8cm, minimum height = .8cm] {} (x);
\path[name path=midneast] (midn.north east) to (midn.south east);
\path[name path=midnwest] (midn.north west) to (midn.south west);
\node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = {varToNoise} and midneast}] (E) at  (intersection-1) {};
\node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = {varToNoise} and midnwest}] (W) at  (intersection-1) {};
draw [dot diameter = 2pt, dot spacing = .3cm, dots ] (E) to (W);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a `\` in `draw` in the last line.

```
draw [dot diameter = 2pt, dot spacing = .3cm, dots ] (E) to (W);
```

Then it works your way.

The `intersection` is not needed but you have to add `sloped` option to the node `midn`:

```
\draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt, name path=varToNoise] (noiseVar) to 
node (midn) [pos=.3, fill=white, minimum width = .8cm, minimum height = .8cm,sloped] {} (x);
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, arrows, calc, intersections}
\tikzset{hidden node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=.8cm,inner sep=0pt}, }
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[hidden node] (noiseVar) at (5,4) {$\sigma²_n$};
\node[hidden node] (noise) at (0,4) {$\varepsilon$};
\node[hidden node] (x) at (0,0) {$x$};

\draw[line width=2] (noiseVar) to node (midf) [pos=.3, fill=white, minimum width = .8cm] {} (noise);
\draw[dot diameter = 2pt, dot spacing = .3cm, dots] (midf.east) to (midf.west);

\draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt, name path=varToNoise] (noiseVar) to node (midn) [pos=.3, fill=white, minimum width = .8cm, minimum height = .8cm,sloped] {} (x);
%\path[name path=midneast] (midn.north east) to (midn.south east);
%\path[name path=midnwest] (midn.north west) to (midn.south west);
%\node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = {varToNoise} and midneast}] (E) at  (intersection-1) {};
%\node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = {varToNoise} and midnwest}] (W) at  (intersection-1) {};
\draw [dot diameter = 2pt, dot spacing = .3cm, dots ] (midn.west) to (midn.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sorry for the silly mistake. However, I am glad to have learnt the sloped option. I still wonder if there is a more straightforward way to have different styles across a line.

Comment: @PabloGuerrero If `sloped` is not straight forward enough, then using `decorations` will be less straight forward, I hope ;-)